# Error de Inicio de Sesión de la aplicación al servidor SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server

Antes que nada, les agradezco por tomarse el tiempo de leer mi problema el cual es el siguiente.

Hace algunos meses he estado trabajando en un sistema el cual conecta 4 computadoras a un servidor de manera local. Me ha funcionado perfectamente y las actualizaciones igual. Aunque, cuando agregué la última actualización que he hecho me aparece el siguiente error: [image: lOGIN FAILED]

Obviamente he buscado como solucionarlo en Internet... sin embargo, varios de las soluciones no las entiendo. Espero y puedan ayudarme... les dejo el código con el que siempre me he conectado al servidor.

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MenuInicio.conexion = new SqlConnection();
        string ConexionSQL = "Server =Nombredelservidor;Database=Nombredelabasededatos;UID=" + usuario.Text + ";PWD=" + contraseña.Text + ""
        MenuInicio.conexion.ConnectionString = ConexionSQL;
        try
        {
            MenuInicio.conexion.Open();
            if(MenuInicio.conexion.State==ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Estableciendo Conexion a la Base de Datos", this.Text, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                for (int x = 0; x < 1000000; x++)
                {
                    if (x % 1000 == 0)
                    {
                        Cargando.PerformStep();
                    }
                }   
                MenuInicio menu = new MenuInicio();
                menu.Show();
                this.Hide();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("No se pudo establecer conexion", this.Text, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Stop);
            }
        }
        catch(SqlException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Usuario o Contraseña Incorrectos: " + ex.Message, this.Text, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
```

El error entra en el primer try-catch. he intentado creando otro usuario con contraseña.
si tiene el método de autentificación Mixto.

Lo curioso es que si me conecto desde otro SQL a ese servidor si conecta... y si instalo el sistema en mi laptop(en donde estoy creando el sistema) también conecta.

ESPERO Y PUEDAN AYUDARME POR FAVOR!. 
Por su atención, ¡GRACIAS!

Comment: El sistema se conecta a un servidor SQL Server, el manejador de base de datos que utilizo es el Management Studio. Lo conectaba por medio de su direccion IP pero esta me cambiaba seguido, por ello lo empece a conectar por el nombre del servidor.

Comment: Perdona, ya vi `MenuInicio.conexion = new SqlConnection();`. Diría que tu cadena de conexion es incorrecta. Sería algo como `Server=Nombredelservidor;Database=Nombredelabasededatos;User Id=" + usuario.Text + ";Password=" + contraseña.Text + ""`

Comment: El problema radica cuando instalo el sistema en otra computadora me sale ese error, en la computadora donde estoy creando el sistema si conecta, pero cuando paso el sistema a otra pc ya sale ese error. De igual forma ya cambie a linea de codigo por la que tu me diste

Comment: El error que mencionas solo deberia aparecer si usaras una ' trusted connection'  para hacer el login. Como no es asi, he visto que tu cadena de conexion no es correcta ya que `UID` y `PWD` solo se usa si la conexion es OLEDB, pero tu usas una conexion SqlConnection, con lo que la cadena debe usar  `User Id` y `Password`. Si eso no soluciona el problema, entramos en algo mas complejo que puede ser dificil de resolver sin analizar mejor tu caso en concreto.

Comment: Data Source=xxx;Initial Catalog=xxx;User ID=xxx;Password=xxxx usa esta cadena y comentas como te va

Comment: Ya cambie la cadena a como tu me dijiste bro, lo que s eme hace extaño es por que siempre habia funcionado asi y de repente en una ultima actualizacion se descompuso... sera problema de las propiedades del sistema o del Servidor...

Comment: Si, lo raro es que tu cadena no debería haber funcionado nunca, pero me temo que por alguna razon estaba usando el usuario windows para loguearse y no el usuario que le pasabas. De todas maneras, te funciona tras cambiarlo a lo que te dije?

Comment: @Manny diría que esa cadena de conexion es para una conexion OLEDB, no para SqlServer

Comment: No bro, aun no... en mi laptop (donde estoy haciendo el sistema) si entra, si conecta pero paso el setup e instalo en una pc y sigue apareciendo el erro. de igual manera muchisimas gracias por ayudarme, creo que el problema esta o en las configuraciones del instalador, las propiedades del sistema o en el servidor.

Comment: Puedes probar a conectarte con el Management Studio desde el pc que te da problemas al servidor, a ver si funciona o te da el mismo problema. Siento no poder ayudarte mas

Comment: date una vuelta por aqui y quizas alguna conexion de sirva https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/

Comment: Ya he probado conectarme desde el sql server de mi lap a la del servidor y si conecta, desde el SGBD a otro no hay ningun problema. Justo ahora hice mi laptop servidor, para ver si desde otra pc con el sistema puedo conectarme pero me sigue apareciendo el error. Lo que se me viene a la mente que no es el Servidor o la linea de conecction... si no algo relacionado con la red o con las propiedades de la misma o del sistema. De igual manera en cuanto lo resueva aviso que era lo que tenia. pero me preocupa mucho ya que solo se puede alimentar la bd desde mi lap.

Comment: Agrega a tu cadena se conexion: Persist Security Info=False para que puedas conectarte con el esquema mixto. De lo contrario tratara de autenticarse via Windows y al parecer tus dominios no son de confianza

Comment: Si les soy muy sincero no tengo ni idea de que tenia el sistema... No pude componerlo, gracias a que tenia una version para escritorios con pantalla cuadrada vi que si hagarraba esa version... lo unico que hice fue pasar las actualizaciones a esa version... no logro entender por que con la actualizacion esa no conecta... igual si alguien lee esto y puede que sepa por que, escucho comentarios... no puedo quedarme con esa duda... tambien compare ambos archivos y sinceramente no encontre diferencias...